# Printing nested arrays

Tags: php, mysql

My database:

[image: Database]

Class:

```
Class Category {
    function __construct($db) {
        $this->db = $db;
    }

    public function groupByUnderCategoryName() {
        $query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT categoryName, id, title FROM test2");
        $query->execute();
        return $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_GROUP);      
    }
}
```

Seeing picture above, probably first thing comes to mind is, creating another table for categories and JOIN them. Actually that is what I already did, please see above picture as a result of joining two tables.

This is result of above query:

```
array (size=3)
  'Action' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => 
        object(stdClass)[5]
          public 'id' => string '1' (length=1)
          public 'title' => string 'Action#1' (length=8)
      1 => 
        object(stdClass)[7]
          public 'id' => string '3' (length=1)
          public 'title' => string 'Action#2' (length=8)
  'Drama' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => 
        object(stdClass)[6]
          public 'id' => string '2' (length=1)
          public 'title' => string 'Drama#1' (length=7)
      1 => 
        object(stdClass)[9]
          public 'id' => string '5' (length=1)
          public 'title' => string 'Drama#1' (length=7)
  'Comedy' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        object(stdClass)[8]
          public 'id' => string '4' (length=1)
          public 'title' => string 'Comedy#1' (length=8)
```

As very proud I am to use `PDO::FETCH_GROUP` to get result above, I am not sure if it's a good idea to print it like that, and I would like you to review and help with me better practice:

```
$category = new Category($db);

foreach ($category->groupByUnderCategoryName() as $key => $value) {
    echo "<h3>{$key}</h3>";

    foreach ($value as $t_value) {
        echo "<h4>{$t_value->title}</h4>";
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: result]

Comment: Why do you think it's not a good idea?

Comment: @YourCommonSense, foreach loop inside of another foreach loop seemed only solution to me, but I think avoiding the nesting would be better. maybe.

Comment: If you have an array, the only way to iterate it over is a loop. It means that if you have a nested array, then a nested loop is the only way.

Comment: Glad to hear that from your side, so just leaving code here since I believe it can be very helpful for future visitors.